# Maya 2018 QT Designer UI Python Bindings

Tags: python, user-interface, binding, maya, qt-designer

I have some questions regarding "*Maya 2018 QT Designer UI Python Bindings*". I´m trying to bind my UI from QT Designer into Maya 2018.

I found this code from the Maya Docs:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

ui_filename = cmds.loadUI(f='C:/02_Python/UIs/Main.ui')
cmds.showWindow(ui_filename)
```

This works fine so far. Now I want to bind the `QLineEdit:textField`, `QPushButton:button`, `QWidget:control`, etc.
with maya Functions. I tried many things, but it does not work.

And there's no Code snippet available.

Question: do you have any Code snippet for me to reach my target?
Many thanks for any help on this.

[[image: ScreenShot]]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>294</width>
    <height>86</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Maya Box</string>
  </property>
  <property name="windowIcon">
   <iconset>
    <normaloff>icons/Maya2018.ico</normaloff>icons/Maya2018.ico</iconset>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">/*
MAIN WIDGET
/**********************************************************************/

QWidget{
    color:  rgb( 255, 255, 255 );
    background-color: rgb( 80, 80, 80 );
}

/*
TOOL TIP
/**********************************************************************/

QToolTip{ 
    color: rgb( 0, 0, 0 ); 
    background-color: #FFFFE1;
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* 
SPLITTER
/**********************************************************************/
QSplitter::handle{
    image: url(:/Splitter.png);
}

QSplitter::handle:pressed{
    image: url(:/Splitter_active.png);
}

/*
MENU BAR
/**********************************************************************/

 QMenuBar {
  background-color: rgb( 65, 65, 65 );
 }

 QMenuBar::item {
  spacing: 3px;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
 }

 QMenuBar::item:selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb( 127, 127, 127 );
  background: transparent;
 }

 QMenuBar::item:pressed {
  background:  rgb( 127, 127, 127 );
 }

/* 
DOCK WIDGET
/**********************************************************************/

QDockWidget {
    titlebar-close-icon: url(:/Exit.png);
}

QDockWidget &gt; QWidget {
    border: 1px solid rgb( 45, 45, 45 );
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}

QDockWidget:close-button, QDockWidget::close-button:hover {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    icon-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 2px;
}

QDockWidget::title{
    border-top-left-radius: 2px;
    border-top-right-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:0.0, y2:1.0, stop:0.0 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255), stop:0.15 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.45 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.48 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255), stop:1.0 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255));
}

/* 
TOOL BAR
/**********************************************************************/

QToolBar:top, QToolBar:bottom {
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;
    spacing: 0px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:0.0, y2:1.0, stop:0.0 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255), stop:0.15 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.45 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.48 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255), stop:1.0 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255));
}

QToolBar:left, QToolBar:right{
    border: none;
    border-radius: none;
    spacing: 0px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:1.0, y2:0.0, stop:0.0 rgba(110, 110, 110, 255), stop:0.15 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.45 rgba(75, 75, 75, 255), stop:0.48 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255), stop:1.0 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255));
}

QToolBar::handle{
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
}

/*
TAB WIDGET
/**********************************************************************/

QTabWidget::pane:top, QTabWidget::pane:left{
    border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
    top: -1px;
}

/*
DOUBLE SPIN BOX
/**********************************************************************/

QDoubleSpinBox:hover, QDoubleSpinBox:focus{
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QDoubleSpinBox:enabled{
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QDoubleSpinBox:disabled{
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(90, 90, 90), stop:1 rgba(70, 70, 70));
}

QDoubleSpinBox::up-button:enabled, QDoubleSpinBox::down-button:enabled{
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

QDoubleSpinBox::up-button:disabled, QDoubleSpinBox::down-button:disabled{
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
}

QDoubleSpinBox::up-arrow:enabled{
    image: url(:/upArrow.png);
}

QDoubleSpinBox::down-arrow:enabled{
    image: url(:/downArrow.png);
}

/*
LIST WIDGET
/**********************************************************************/

QListWidget{ 
  color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); 
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-radius: 1px;
  alternate-background-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
}

QListWidget::item:selected, QListWidget::item:selected:hover, QListWidget::item:pressed{ 
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); 
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb( 218, 165, 32 );
}

QListWidget::item:hover{ 
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); 
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

QListView::item:selected:active {
    color: rgb( 255, 255, 255 ); 
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(154, 205, 50);
}

QListWidget::indicator { 
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

QListWidget::indicator:unchecked:enabled, QListWidget::indicator:indeterminate:enabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QListWidget::indicator:checked:enabled {
    image: url(:/checked.png);
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QListWidget::indicator:unchecked:hover, QListWidget::indicator:checked:hover {
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*
SLIDER
/**********************************************************************/

QSlider::groove:horizontal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px; bottom: 4px;
    height: 6px;
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:enabled {
    width: 6px;
    margin: -4px, -4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(150, 150, 150), stop:1 rgb(130, 130, 130));
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:disabled {
    width: 6px;
    margin: -4px, -4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
}

QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover, QSlider::handle:horizontal:focus {
    width: 6px;
    margin: -4px, -4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(150, 150, 150), stop:1 rgb(130, 130, 130));
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
}

QSlider::add-page:horizontal:enabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:enabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(127, 127, 127), stop:1 rgb(100, 100, 100));
}

QSlider::sub-page:horizontal:disabled, QSlider::add-page:horizontal:disabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/*
COMBO BOX
/**********************************************************************/

QComboBox {
    width: 100px;
}

QComboBox::down-arrow:enabled {
    image: url(:/downArrow.png);
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    background: rgb(110, 110, 110);
}

QComboBox:enabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QComboBox:hover {
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QComboBox::drop-down:enabled {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QComboBox:disabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(90, 90, 90), stop:1 rgba(70, 70, 70));
}

QComboBox::drop-down:disabled {
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(90, 90, 90), stop:1 rgba(70, 70, 70));
}

/*
MENU
/**********************************************************************/

QMenu {
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(45, 45, 45);
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.2, x2:0.0, y2:0.6, stop:0 rgb(45, 45, 45), stop:1 rgb(60, 60, 60));
}

QMenu::item {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

QMenu::item:selected {
    color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.3, x2:0.0, y2:0.7, stop:0 rgba(243, 143, 28, 255), stop: 1 rgba(242, 158, 25, 255));
}

/*
CHECK BOX
/**********************************************************************/

QCheckBox::indicator {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:enabled, QCheckBox::indicator:indeterminate:enabled {
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:checked:enabled {
    image: url(:/checked.png);
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

QCheckBox::indicator:unchecked:hover, QCheckBox::indicator:checked:hover {
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*
PUSH BUTTON
/**********************************************************************/

QPushButton {
  width: 16px;
  padding: 2px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.4, x2:0.0, y2:0.55, stop:0 rgba(65, 65, 65,  255), stop:1 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255));
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: bold
}

QPushButton:default {
   border-color: rgba(166, 133, 99, 255);
   border-radius: 3px;
}

QPushButton:hover {
  border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

QPushButton:pressed {
  border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.4, x2:0.0, y2:0.55, stop:0 rgba(45, 45, 45, 255), stop:1 rgba(25, 25, 25, 255));
  color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

QPushButton:checked {
  border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

QPushButton[activeViewpoint=&quot;true&quot;] {
  border: 1px outset rgba(244, 244, 244, 255);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

QPushButton:hover[activeViewpoint=&quot;true&quot;] {
  border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/*
TOOL BUTTON
/**********************************************************************/

QToolButton {
    border: none;
    background: none;
}

QToolButton:hover, QToolButton:checked {
    border: none;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 120);
}

QToolButton:menu-arrow {
    margin-top: 40;
    background: none;
    image: url(:/downArrow.png);
}

QToolButton[popupMode=&quot;1&quot;]{
    padding-right: 10px;
}

QToolButton:menu-button{
    border:  none;
}

/*
LINE EDIT
/**********************************************************************/

QLineEdit{
    border: 1px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

QLineEdit:hover {
    border: 1px outset rgba(244, 133, 22, 255);
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1 rgba(90, 90, 90));
}

/*
GROUP BOX
/**********************************************************************/

QGroupBox{
  border: 2px solid rgb(127, 127, 127);
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
}

/*
TAB BAR
/**********************************************************************/

QTabBar::tab:top:selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:0.0, y2:1.0, stop:0.0 rgb(252, 194, 0), stop:0.1 rgb(236, 122, 40), stop:0.15 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1.0 rgb(80, 80, 80));
}

QTabBar::tab:top:!selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(70, 70, 70), stop:1 rgba(60, 60, 60));
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-top: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:0.0, y2:1.0, stop:0.0 rgb(70, 70, 70), stop:0.89 rgb(100, 100, 100), stop:0.9 rgb(236, 122, 40), stop:1.0 rgb(252, 194, 0));
}

QTabBar::tab:bottom:!selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 6px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.55, x2:0.0, y2:0.9, stop:0 rgb(55, 55, 55), stop:1 rgba(65, 65, 65));
}

QTabBar::tab:left:selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-left: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:1.0, y2:0.0, stop:0.0 rgb(80, 80, 80), stop:0.89 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:0.9 rgb(236, 122, 40), stop:1.0 rgb(252, 194, 0));
}

QTabBar::tab:left:!selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  padding: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  margin-right: 4px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(70, 70, 70), stop:1 rgba(60, 60, 60));
}

QTabBar::tab:right:selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-right: 0px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 6px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.0, x2:1.0, y2:0.0, stop:0.0 rgb(252, 194, 0), stop:0.1 rgb(236, 122, 40), stop:0.15 rgb(110, 110, 110), stop:1.0 rgb(80, 80, 80));
}

QTabBar::tab:right:!selected {
  border: 1px solid rgb(110, 110, 110);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  background: qlineargradient(x1:0.0, y1:0.1, x2:0.0, y2:0.45, stop:0 rgb(90, 90, 90), stop:1 rgba(70, 70, 70));
}</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="text">
      <string>Path to File</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_Path">
       <property name="text">
        <string>c:\_data_\*.txt</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QToolButton" name="toolButton_Path">
       <property name="text">
        <string>...</string>
       </property>
       <property name="icon">
        <iconset>
         <normalon>icons/folder.ico</normalon>
        </iconset>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
     <item>
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_O">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>128</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>OK</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_C">
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>128</width>
         <height>0</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Cancel</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
       <property name="orientation">
        <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>20</height>
        </size>
       </property>
      </spacer>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation from maya about it :
https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_CEC1D76B_7568_4DCA_B80B_1DE49362492C_htm

Bare in mind that this commnad is not giving access to a standard qt ui.
You might want instead using : `pyuic5 -x file.ui -o file.py`
In order to use proper python code instead of an automatic binding !

Comment: Hi DrWeeny, many thanks for your support on this. I was hoping to find a outof the box solution. I think I´m going to use PySide2 or rebuild the ui with the Maya Windows Functions. anyway, to me it looks like the QT.ui Stuff is not realy implemented yet. Hope this will come in the future. many thanks! Best regards.

Comment: you just need to put the maya flags into qtdesigner with a def you will have created. cmds.loadUI() is just an easy converter but it won't be updated. QtDesigner has already pyuic5 to convert a .ui to .py

Comment: oh, yes. I did not thought about it. Great Tip. Many thanks!